# CSS background not showing up on mobile

Tags: iphone, html, css, mobile, background-image

I am having trouble with my background image not showing up correctly when viewing the site on a mobile device specifically an iPhone. I can see it there its just not in the right place. I have attached a link to the image showing how the background is rendering and a link to the site.

If anyone has an answer to fix this issue I would really appreciate any advice.

Thanks in advance.

http://mikedemar.com/weightloss4youth/bgissue

http://mikedemar.com/weightloss4youth/index.html

Comment: I would try adding `background-size: 100%;` to start with and see from there.

Comment: Good thought, but this messed up the background when viewing on the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine suggested that I remove the "width=device-width" and to set the background-size to 2560px 1440px. This is working perfectly. See link.

http://mikedemar.com/weightloss4youth/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
html { 
        background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

You can see other methods at: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: This seemed to help a little but the background is still not quite right. See link below.

http://mikedemar.com/weightloss4youth/bgissue01.png